# The difference between tf.nn.conv2d_transpose and slim.conv2d_transpose

Tags: tensorflow, deconvolution

What is the difference between this two function in Tensorflow

```
tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(
    value,
    filter,
    output_shape,
    strides,
    padding='SAME',
    data_format='NHWC',
    name=None
)
```

It full defination is in [tf.nn.conv2d_transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose)
slim.conv2d_transpose is define as follow:

```
tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(
    inputs,
    filters,
    kernel_size,
    strides=(1, 1),
    padding='valid',
    data_format='channels_last',
    activation=None,
    use_bias=True,
    kernel_initializer=None,
    bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
    kernel_regularizer=None,
    bias_regularizer=None,
    activity_regularizer=None,
    kernel_constraint=None,
    bias_constraint=None,
    trainable=True,
    name=None,
    reuse=None
)
```

full defination is in [slim.conv2d_transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d_transpose)

how can I define the output shape in slim.conv2d_transpose

Answer (score 4):

There is a significant difference between them. While `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` represents an operation in the computational graph, `tf.layers.conv2d_transpose` defines the entire layer.

Being more precise `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` applies a convolutional `filter` to the `inputs`.

`tf.layers.conv2d_transpose`, on the other hand, first creates trainable variables that will serve as `filter` according to the arguments given, and then it internally calls some `conv2d_transpose` operation. Based on the arguments, it also applies some other operations as adding bias, applying non-linearity, or normalizing the weights or inputs.

With `tf.layers.conv2d_transpose` you do not specify `output shape` as it is computed from filter size, input size, and stride. [Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/36847) is the formula.